# Vim Errors from lh plugin?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I keep receiving this error whenever I open markdown files. I'm assuming it's an `lh` plugin in my autoload folder.

```
Vim:E492: Not an editor command: Brackets < > -visual=0       -open=function('lh#html#brackets#lt')      -clos=function('lh#html#brackets#gt')
```

I've removed the folder, but still no luck. I'm unsure of how to go about debugging this, and was wondering if anyone could help me out?

Basically, that error pops up, and then I lose any syntax highlighting in vim, as well as the ability to use other plugins — `fugitive`, etc.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have your vim config (.vimrc + .vim folder) hosted anywhere we can take a look?  It's tough to try to troubleshoot with no knowledge of your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install [lh-brackets,](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-brackets) which requires in turn [lh-vim-lib](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib).

May I ask where did you get the ftplugin that was requiring my bracketing plugin ? (as I don't know many users using it, I'm quite curious ^^)

Comment: Awesome. You're a lifesaver. I've been using the [Janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) distribution, and an older version included your `lh` plugin. Thanks for your help!